# How to make a workable comment system using blogger api v3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I using blogger and my website is https://scienhac.blogspot.com/
i want to add comment page so user can comment but how i use blogger api i try

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="comments">
      <h2>Comments</h2>
      <ul id="comment-list"></ul>
      <form id="comment-form">
        <label for="name-input">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-input" required />
        <label for="email-input">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email-input" required />
        <label for="comment-input">Comment:</label>
        <textarea id="comment-input" required></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="comment-container"></div>
    <script>
      let x = document.querySelector("#comment-form");
      x.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      const postID = "943659869113432918";
      const blogID = "9160331485130872315";
      const apiKey = "mykey";

      // Retrieve existing comments and display them on the page
      function getComments(postID) {
        const requestUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/${blogID}/posts/${postID}/comments?key=${apiKey}`;

        fetch(requestUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            const comments = data.items;
            comments.forEach((comment) => {
              const commentHtml = `
                <div class="comment">
                    <p class="comment-author">${comment.author.displayName} says:</p>
                    <p class="comment-text">${comment.content}</p>
                </div>
                `;
              document
                .getElementById("comment-container")
                .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", commentHtml);
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      }

      // Post a new comment
      function postComment(postID, name, email, comment) {
        const requestUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/${blogID}/posts/${postID}/comments?key=${apiKey}`;

        const commentData = {
          content: comment,
          author: {
            displayName: name,
          },
          blog: {
            id: blogID,
          },
          post: {
            id: postID,
          },
        };

        fetch(requestUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(commentData),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            // Add the new comment to the comment container
            const commentHtml = `
                <div class="comment">
                <p class="comment-author">${data.author.displayName} says:</p>
                <p class="comment-text">${data.content}</p>
                </div>
            `;
            document
              .getElementById("comment-container")
              .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", commentHtml);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }

      // Attach event listener to the comment form
      document
        .getElementById("comment-form")
        .addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();

          const name = document.getElementById("name-input").value;
          const email = document.getElementById("email-input").value;
          const comment = document.getElementById("comment-input").value;

          // Post the new comment
          postComment(postID, name, email, comment);

          // Clear the input fields
          document.getElementById("name-input").value = "";
          document.getElementById("email-input").value = "";
          document.getElementById("comment-input").value = "";
        });

      // Call getComments to retrieve existing comments
      getComments(postID);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const postID = '943659869113432918';
const blogID = '9160331485130872315';
const apiKey = 'mykey';
var commentData = {
    'content': 'This is a test comment.'
};

const requestUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/${blogID}/posts/${postID}/comments?key=${apiKey}`;

// Make the request to insert the comment
fetch(requestUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(commentData)
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
</script>
```

not works for blogid and postid i automate it i show you blogid and postid according to standard js but i use data:blogid etc //---> so how i made it sometime cors error or sometime any other error i receive

I want a comment page template i modigy it but it lowest scale send fetch and delete option must have

Comment: Just noticed that you have disclosed your API key in the code you shared. That can be harmful if that is your actual API key. I suggest changing your key immediately